# Can't change font color in Libgdx

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I'm trying to change the color of the font I use in my application. But whatever I try the font remains black. 
I made this font using Hiero font tool.

My code is something like this:

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
BitmapFont font = new BtimapFont( Gdx.files.internal(MainAssets.pathToAssets + "font/comic.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal(MainAssets.pathToAssets +  "font/comic.png"), false );
```

In render where I draw the font:

```
batch.begin();
font.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
font.draw(batch, "Hello World!", 0, 0);
batch.end();
```

I found a similar issue to mine but there was still no solution.

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=370

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your font is black then it won't be colour tinted (which is what you're doing when calling setColor). Try generating the font in Hiero again in white.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried both white and black fonts, but not able to change color.

Answer (score 22):

You need to set output format with 32-bit depth and white colour with alpha (in case you are using [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) tool, dont know about the Hiero ).

Answer (score 14):

you can use this

```
font.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with latest libGDX and in my case it was about font image format. For details check this message:

[font.setColor method not working after libGDX update to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487053/font-setcolor-method-not-working-after-libgdx-update-to-latest-version)