# font.setColor method not working after libGDX update to latest version

Tags: fonts, colors, libgdx

I have some 3-4 years old game project in libGDX. Now I decided to update it and to move from Eclipse to Android studio. So, I installed A.S. downloaded and installed fresh libGDX project. Then added my old source files and assets. All went well, with some minor changes game runs. Except font.setColor is not working any more - text on screen is black. Transparency is not working neither. That worked well before.

So, my font is generated with Hiero, and it's white (I saw that in some other questions here that it must be white).

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/bundy.fnt"),
                Gdx.files.internal("fonts/bundy_0.png"), false);
...

font.setColor(0.2f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
font.draw(game.batch, "MAP" , 835,580);
```

To mention that I used

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
```

but now I moved to

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
```

since GL10 is not supported any more.

Also, now I'm using `GlyphLayout` class to get text boundaries. I don't see any other change that could have any influence to font color.

Any idea why setColor is not working? Is there some new step added  meanwhile that I have to do?

Comment: I did the same as you, updated my old projects to IntelliJ and new version of libgdx (1.9.5), had to use GlyphLayout etc. My font.setColor() is working perfectly fine, so I'm sure thats not your problem.

Comment: Something has been changed definitely. The source code is the same, the font files also.

Comment: What picture format are you using for font file? My is 8bit png.

Comment: I dont know xd, created the font in hiero ages ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it!

So, old font image file, that was working well on old libGDX, but won't work in new was in 8 bit png grayscale. Letters were white and background was black.

Now I generated new font with latest Hiero and it was in 8bit png, but in color mode, with white letters and TRANSPARENT background and that works well.

So it was about image format.

P.S. Transparency is still not working...but I can live with that.

Comment: maybe the transparency doesnt work because of the 8 bits? arent more bits needed for transparency?

Comment: Why minus? If it was working with older version of framework and methods, parameters or anything else was not changed it should work with newer version too. You can't just quit supporting some format.

Comment: I upvoted you because this is a correct answer, I dont know who downvoted you.